# Create multi dimensional array.

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

How can I create an array like the following in PHP from a database result set.

```
Array (
 [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => Little Hacienda [is_open] => 0 [order] => 0 )
 [1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [name] => testcat [is_open] => 0 [order] => 0 )
 [2] => Array ( [id] => 3 [name] => fgf [is_open] => 0 [order] => 0 )
 )
```

I have the following code,

```
$arr = array();
$r = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE id=".$key."");
    if (mysql_num_rows($r) > 0){
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($r);
        $f = mysql_num_rows($r);
        for($j = 0; $j < count($f); $j++){
            $arr[$j] = $row[$f[$j]['field']];               

        }
    }
         $test = array();
     array_push($test, $arr);
     return $test;
```

but this returns array

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => Little Hacienda [2] => 0 [3] => 0 ) )
```

Any help will be much appreciated..

Comment: Can you `print_r($row)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like:

```
$arr = array();
$r = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE id='".$key."'");
if (mysql_num_rows($r) > 0) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($r);
    $i = 0;
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($r)) {
        $arr[$i] = $row;
        ++$i;
    }
}
$test = array();
array_push($test, $arr);
return $test;
```

Comment: You don't even need the counter. You can just do `$arr[] = ` which will auto increment the array.

Comment: Additionally if you can't use `$arr[] = ` for any reason you can actually put the `$i++` in the square brackets (`$arr[$i++] = $row;`)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$arr = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc())
{
    $arr[] = $row;
}
```

But I can't leave without the obligatory "[You shouldn't be using a deprecated library](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)".

Mysql library is deprecated and should no longer be used. Please look into using the [MySQL PDO](http://nz1.php.net/pdo_mysql) (a nice OOP interface) or the [Mysqli library](http://nz1.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php).